# how to run aggregated update report?

Tags: sbt

If one types `update` in the sbt console, it runs an aggregated report that typically takes a minute or so for a project.

However, if one programatically runs `update` for each `ProjectRef` it is cronically slow (10 minutes to an hour is not unheard of).

How can one programmatically run the same (faster) aggregated `update` report that the console runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this PR is how I ended up doing it

https://github.com/ensime/ensime-sbt/pull/122

which meant setting up an aggregated report in a single task and calling that once, which is referenced later on.

Answer (score 1):

> If one types update in the sbt console, it runs an aggregated report that typically takes a minute or so for a project.

The implementation of the `update` task is available here:

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-zero-thirteen/blob/v0.13.9/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L1325-L1443

The main thing it adds there is caching based on the input parameters.

Not sure what you mean by aggregated. Do you mean aggregated across the configurations (e.g. `Compile` and `Test`?)

Comment: great! I think that's what I mean, yes.I actually found this `updateTask` when investigating, but I didn't know how to invoke it. Any hints for application here? https://github.com/fommil/ensime-sbt/blob/harder_better_faster/src/main/scala/EnsimePlugin.scala#L197

Comment: I might also mean aggregated across all the submodules. I'm not 100% sure what the differences are between the two ways of invoking `update`.

Comment: the `Initialize.evaluate` looks like what I want, but it takes some `Setting` parameters that I don't have.